# Workarounds for strongly-typed ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given that strongly typed `ActionLink` is not viable ( [Strongly Typed ActionLink In Asp.Net MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240123/strongly-typed-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc-2) ) and we cannot do something like:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(x => x.Index(), "Home") %>
```

I am considering using either classes of `static readonly string` or resource files as a workaround. This would get some level of compile time checking, allow for renaming without using find/replace, and even (in some crazy world) allow for localization. On the downside, it requires duplicate information about available controllers and actions to work.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Controllers.Home, HomeActions.Index, HomeActions.IndexTitle) %>
```

Any suggestions for other ways to handle this that improves on the inelegant default of using magic strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [T4 Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/06/17/a-new-and-improved-asp-net-mvc-t4-template.aspx). Or [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) contains helpers which would allow you to have the exact same syntax as you showed in your question:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(x => x.Index(), "Home") %>
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White, great, glad we are on the same wave :-)