# Considerations for strongly typed ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to find more information about the Strongly typed ActionLink helper method that debuted in Futures.  I understand that there are some strong disadvantages to using it, but would like to know more.  The best link I have found is this one.

[Strongly Typed ActionLink In Asp.Net MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240123/strongly-typed-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

The explanation in the above link is brief enough, and my knowledge of what is under the hood with MVC is thin enough, that I'm having trouble discarding what, on the surface, seems a preferable way to generate URLs.

So my question(s):

- Is there any updated information on the status of this in MVC 3?
- And is there anywhere that its disadvantages have been explained in more depth?

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe the answer you were looking for is in this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/02/alternative-to-expressions.aspx) by Phil Haack and in this [slide deck](http://www.slideshare.net/rudib/aspnet-mvc-performance) by Rudi Benkovic.

Basically, it's a performance issue. It takes ASP.NET MVC about 30 times longer to figure out the route for a link when using the fancy expression syntax vs. the "magic string" syntax.

You may find that the performance trade-off is worth it. If not, [T4MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/T4MVC) is probably the best alternative you're going to find.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer any of your questions, but it possibly gives a nice alternative:
Check out [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/)

From the description:

e.g. instead of

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", "Delete", "Dinners", new { id = Model.DinnerID }, null)
```

T4MVC lets you write

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Dinner", MVC.Dinners.Delete(Model.DinnerID))
```

Answer (score 1):

The description of how this works that you linked to is pretty clear: "given this information and assuming no extensibility hooks, guess which route will hit this action". If you don't plan to change customize the way your application uses routes too much, you should be fine.

It still requires the [Futures Package](http://nuget.org/packages/Mvc3Futures) if you want to use the extension method.